# Unable to install Freezed with flutter because freezed depends on freezed?

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, flutter-freezed

I want to try the Freezed package with flutter, I follow the setup steps in the package [readme](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaThk0fiphA).

But when I enter the command to add the freezed package;

```
flutter pub add --dev freezed
```

, got the following error message :

```
Because freezed depends on freezed, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 65
```

I don't understand why freezed depends on freezed !?

If I add freezed in the pubspec.yaml file I go the same error:

```
Error on line 51, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.
   ╷
51 │   freezed : any
   │   ^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

I use Flutter 3.0.1 with Dart 2.17.1 on Linux 22.04.
I found nohting in the Freezed github issues or googeling.

Any idea, suggestions ?

Thank's,

Constant

Comment: Could you please add your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: Can you check if the name of your flutter project is also `freezed`?

Comment: @kforjan I'll check later, but I think it's that :-(

Comment: @kforjan, you where rigth my project was colald `freezed`, thanks